# how to connect database client from server?

Tags: database, ms-access, select, client

Is it possible to (select query) of Microsoft Access database from my server where the MDB file is located in **client pc** (not in server)?
Global question: how to interact with client database (MS Accces) from my server(web site)???

Comment: The answer to your first question is Yes.  It is possible.  You're second question is not "global"... it is *very* vague.  Specifics are necessary is questions on this site.  Please see [ask] as well as [mcve] and also [help/on-topic].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Yes, please be sure to take the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/Tour - the basic idea is that the best questions will show specific code that has been tried, then show the error or whatever is stopping progress.  Then pose a specific question about the error, then copy that question into the title.  That is the way to attract the most useful answers, and to contribute to the database.  Always remember that Google users are likely to find answers in this SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to rethink your setup:

- Better have your database MDB on the server (Web server) since the server most likely to have a static IP address

  - Then you can have another database MDB on the client link to the Database MDB on the server (Web server) thru linked tables or ADO

This will be quite a challenge(redefining client/server setup), you better off going with a better DBMS on the server(Web site) like MySQL or MariaDB. Easy to setup and access remotely with MySQL connectors, from your client pc.